# DDD: MailService.SendNotificationToUser() or User.Notify()?

Tags: c#-4.0, domain-driven-design

I seem to stumble on problem after problem giving my entities behaviour.

I have a system where a user gets a notification when someone comments his article. Right now it is via an e-mail.

I'm struggling how to implement this the DDD way.

**Option 1**

User entity has a Notify method: `User.Notify()`
The method uses C# built in classes to send an e-mail notification via e-mail

The problem with having this in the domain is that it is technology specific, and how a user is notified might change in the future. I feel this belongs to infrastructure, but how then can a user have behavior?

**Option 2**

I create a `Service: NotificationService.Notify(User)`
The Service uses C# built in classes to send an e-mail

The pro is that the service could be an Application Service, and as far as I know an application service can use the infrastructure and call things like the System.Net.Mail and repositories for that sake.

How would you implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This operation doesn't seems to be natural part of User entity. This operation is stateless. So, it seems to me that notification is responsibility of service.

This is not domain service, because its not about business logic. Notification service abstracts infrastructure implementations from your domain (User). Notification could use Emails, MSMQ or put messages to database. This should not affect your domain model. So, thats definitely goes to infrastructure.

So, I'd go for option 2. Infrastructure service.

PS Consider about more descriptive method name `NotifyCommentAdded`

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I did not consider state, and this really cleared things up for me.

Comment: One question though, who would use this service. I use MVC so I have a controller action that handles the "add comment". Should I update the DB then send notification there or should a I call a Application Service that adds comment and then calls the Infrastructure Service NotifyCommentAdded. So if iI change UI platform all i really need to care about is invoking the application service, not if, when and how a user is notified?

Comment: I think application service is a good place for this call, because notification is a part of comment adding action. And yes, you are right - it makes logic presentation independent.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is almost 10 years already, OP already probably changed jobs, but my comment can be helpful to new readers.

What do you say to make the notify operation a responsibility of a `Comment` object?
After all in OOP (including DDD) everything is an object, so a `Comment` class is not out of question.
The `notify` method of `Comment` can take as an argument the `User` that has to be notified, resulting in the following signature:

```
Comment#notify(User user)
```

I know that it may seem tightly coupled to the details of notifying (via email, SMS, etc.) but we can reverse this dependency with DI (dependency inversion), resulting in the following constructor signature:

```
Comment#Comment(INotificationService notificationService)
```

Then upon constructing the `Comment` object, you can pass an `EmailNotificationService` or an `SMSNotificationService` both implementing `INotificationService`.

PS: Sorry for the non-C# answer, but I don't really know C#. Instead I invented my own language for this answer.